# How to reach the /etc folder from cd /Macintosh/ HD?

Tags: macos, monterey, sudo

I use Monterey macOS v12.3.

Do you know how can I find the `/etc` folder from the `cd /Macintosh/ HD`?

I corrupted my `sudoers` and I want to modify it from single-user mode, but I am not able to reach the path.
I tried the following looking for `/etc`.

```
 cd /Macintosh/ HD/System/Volumes/Data
 cd /Macintosh/ HD/System/private
```

I read this topic, but there was no clue how to reach it:
[What's /System/Volumes/Data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/whats-system-volumes-data)

### Below is the text taken from the currently closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625339/i-corrupted-my-sudoers-file-on-mac-how-to-modify-from-it-from-single-user-mode) asked at Stack Overflow.

**Title: I corrupted my sudoers file on MAC- how to modify from it from single user mode?**

By mistake, I corrupted my `sudoers` file. I modified it and mis-spelled a word that corrupted the file.

I wrote `NOPASSED` instead of `NOPASSWD`.

In the meantime, I am not able to edit it any more.

I am using a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) with macOS 12.3.

I rebooted with single user mode, and opened the Terminal, but I am not able to reach the directory to modify the file.

###### This log below is from the normal Terminal macOS, not from the single user mode.

```
oahmed@oahmed-mac /etc % ls -l | grep sudo
-r--r-----   1 root wheel      257 26 Feb 02:05 sudo_lecture
-r--r-----   1 root wheel     1573  2 Feb 12:18 sudoers
drwxr-xr-x   2 root wheel       64 26 Feb 02:05 sudoers.d
oahmed@oahmed-mac /etc % more sudoers
sudoers: Permission denied
oahmed@oahmed-mac /etc % sudo vi sudoers
/etc/sudoers:56:34: syntax error
%admin      ALL = (ALL) NOPASSED: ALL
                             ^
Password:
Sorry, user oahmed is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/vi sudoers' as root on oahmed-mac.
```

Comment: I believe `/Macintosh/ HD` should be `/Macintosh\ HD`. Is this what you entered in a Terminal application window or just when entered your question?

Comment: I'd just [download BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) and edit the file with that -- it can edit as root without going through `sudo`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Have you tried to edit `sudoers` with BBEdit. I was able with `hosts`, but not `sudoers`. I had to add user write access to `sudoers`, then I could. However, the OP can not do this because he can not use `sudo`. I was following the instructions given [here](https://www.simplehelp.net/2010/08/23/how-to-edit-the-os-x-hosts-file/).

Comment: Adding NOPASSWD is a bad idea and you should not do it.

Comment: Interesting; I hadn't tried editing /etc/sudoers specifically, but I just did and I get the same result (even after granting "Full Disk Access" to BBedit). I'm not sure what's causing that, but I withdraw the recommendation.

Comment: Did you edit the file without `visudo`? `visudo` is *the* command you should always use to edit `sudoers` *specifically* because it checks for syntax errors before replacing the old files and avoids bricking your system...

Comment: I did edit with normal .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to boot to single user mode to fix your error. What you need to do is switch your user ID to superuser (`root`). Under normal unix, the command would be `su`, however this command will not work as expected until you enable the `root` user. The procedure is given below.

### Enable the `root` User

> Note the lock icon should appear similar to the image shown below.

[image: lock icon]

The steps are given below.

1. Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups (or Accounts).
2. Click the lock icon, then enter an administrator name and password.
3. Click Login Options.
4. Click Join (or Edit).
5. Click Open Directory Utility.
6. Click the lock icon in the Directory Utility window, then enter an administrator name and password.
7. From the menu bar in Directory Utility, choose Edit > Enable Root User, then enter the password that you want to use for the `root` user.
8. Quit System Preferences. For convenience, leave the Directory Utility window open.

### Fix the `sudoers` File

Proceed with the following steps.

1. Goto a Terminal application window and enter the command `su`. Enter the `root` user's password when asked.
2. Once you are the `root` user, make the necessary correction to the `sudoers` file.
3. If locked, click the lock icon in the Directory Utility window, then enter an administrator name and password.
4. From the menu bar in Directory Utility, choose Edit > Disable Root User.
5. Quit the Directory Utility.

### References

- [How to enable the root user on your Mac or change your root password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012)

Comment: That option worked for me, thank you very much

Comment: Omar: If an answer worked for you, then you should accept the answer. This will let others know a solution was found. Also, a green checkmark will appear next to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just did, I am now to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 8):

When booting to singe user mode, the following messages can be observed.

[image]

To access the `/etc` directory, read the above and enter the following commands.

```
/sbin/mount -P 1
/usr/libexec/init_data_protection
/sbin/mount -P 2
```

Entering `ls /etc/sudoers` will result in the following.

```
-sh-3.2# ls /etc/sudoers
/etc/sudoers
```

As you can see, the name of the volume containing the root directory is irrelevant. In other words, you do not need to enter `Macintosh\ HD`.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't show me the file, I wanted to share a screenshot, but there is no option to attach .. I uploaded to my Google drive https://photos.app.goo.gl/4tmLU3nxujfm9vAj6

Comment: Omar: I believe your image shows you are not in single-user mode. I think you are in macOS Recovery or booted from an USB macOS installer. Your question explicitly states the following: *"I want to modify it from single-user mode"*. Additionally, your image shows you entering the command `/sbin/mount -uw /`. My answer does **not** instruct you to enter this command. It is important that you follow the instructions that are actually stated in the answer.

Comment: Hi David:
I am new to Mac, and I thought that mode is the single user mode, but according to your reply, seems it is not that one. Thanks fro clarifying that to me :).
so it seems that was what is called recovery mode. I will google it now to get the single with M1 machine.

Comment: and for the extra command /sbin/mount -uw / , it was there in the screenshot you share, i thought you just missed in the text, actually i tried the steps two time, one time with the command, and one time without.
but anyway, i am the wrong mode in both cases.

Comment: Omar: I did add [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438978/how-to-reach-the-etc-folder-from-cd-macintosh-hd/439152#439152) which explains how to fix the problem from macOS Recovery. This new answer is probably what you were looking for in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

### Using macOS Recovery or a Bootable Installer for macOS

This answer was tested using a bootable installer for macOS 12.0.1 (Build 21A559). You could also boot from macOS Recovery instead.

Here I assume a Terminal window was opened by selecting Utiities > Terminal from the Recovery menubar.

> First, I should note that the OP incorrectly entered `Macintosh/ HD`. Instead, the OP should have used `Macintosh\ HD` or `"Macintosh HD"`.

Execute the steps given below.

1. Enter the command below to invoke a Z shell. The `chroot` command changes the root directory to be the same as when booted to macOS Monterey. If you prefer a Bash shell, then substitute `bash` for `zsh`.

   > Note: If you wish to access any installed third party software, then you may elect to add  `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` variable.

   ```
   chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" zsh
   ```
2. Make the necessary correction to the `sudoers` file. For example, the command below uses the `nano` editor to edit the `sudoers` file.

   ```
   nano /etc/sudoers
   ```

   > Note: User [GACy20](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/424309/gacy20) posted a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/632039) recommending the use of the `visudo` command.
3. When finished, enter the command below to return to the original Bash shell.

   ```
   exit
   ```

Below is sample output.

```
-bash-3.2# chroot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" zsh
root@Mac / # nano /etc/sudoers
root@Mac / # exit

Saving session...shell_session_save:7: read-only file system: /dev/null

...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
-bash-3.2#
```

### References

- [How to access commands included with macOS from macOS Recovery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437343/how-to-access-commands-included-with-macos-from-macos-recovery)
- [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)
- [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)
- [Use macOS Recovery on a Mac with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/mac)
- [Use macOS Recovery on an Intel-based Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac)

Answer (score 0):

This series of answers - all from David Anderson (until now) - are treasures for those of us who feel stymied and/or frustrated by Apple's practice of software, systems development & administration.

I add this answer only to [*augment* the information provided in Mr. Anderson's first answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/438983/149366), and perhaps help other users running older versions of macOS. Specifically:

- I still use macOS Catalina (10.15.6) on my machine (because it has been my *experience* that Apple's upgrades create a larger *risk surface* for dysfunction).
- In following the procedure for enabling the `root` user - which I completed successfully thanks to the detailed recipe - I found that upon completion, the `su` approach remained unavailable to me on my system:

  ```
  % su
  Password:
  su: Sorry
  % <repeated several times>
  ```

  Which seems odd as `su` is definitely installed on Catalina, and is functional for other users (including Admins). Perhaps this was done in `/etc/pam.d/su`?

  **Instead**, I had to resort to this to get the `root` prompt, which of course is *useless* for recovery on a Catalina system (maybe others?) if you had made the OP's spelling error:

  ```
  % sudo su     # or 'sudo su -' if you prefer
  Password:
  sh-3.2# whoami
  root
  sh-3.2#
  ```

  ref addenda notes 1. & 2. in the sequel
- The OP asked another question:

  > Do you know how can I find the `/etc` folder from the `cd /Macintosh/ HD`?
  > * Subsequently corrected to `cd /Macintosh\ HD`

  On my old Catalina system, `Macintosh HD` appears Under `Finder`'s "Locations", but:

  ```
  % cd /Macintosh\ HD
  cd: no such file or directory: /Macintosh HD  
  % cd Macintosh\ HD 
  cd: no such file or directory: Macintosh HD 
  % cd 'Macintosh HD'
  cd: no such file or directory: Macintosh HD
  ```

  Yet, I can see the contents of `Macintosh HD` when I click it in the Finder window. I'm sure it's *just me*: this strikes me as a bit of a *disconnect*... but not a reason to upgrade  :)

  But back to the question at hand, here's what I see when trying to list the contents of the `/etc` folder on my Catalina system:

  ```
  % ls -l /etc
  lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  11 Dec  5  2019 /etc -> private/etc 

  # should this have been '/etc -> /private/etc' ??
  ```

  However, we can get there like this:

  ```
  ~ % cd /etc 
  /etc % ls -l
  total 1072
  -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     515 Nov  9  2019 afpovertcp.cfg
  lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel      15 Dec  5  2019 aliases -> postfix/aliases
  -rw-r-----   1 root  wheel   16384 Nov  9  2019 aliases.db

  ...

  /etc %
  ```
- In closing, wrt editing `/private/etc/sudoers` (*or whatever it's now called*), **NOTE** there is also a folder named :`/private/etc/sudoers.d`

  `sudoers.d` is empty on my Catalina system, but it is *potentially* a great place for adding things like assigning the `NOPASSWD` option (or `NOPASSED` if you prefer :) to a user. Note that if you want to create additional rules in `sudoers.d`, you'll need to include this line in your `sudoers` file:

  > #includedir /etc/sudoers.d

  One should use `visudo -f` for editing files under `sudoers.d` - it does the same syntax & "spelling" checks on the entries, but if an entry is added using a conventional editor, [it is said](https://newbedev.com/why-does-the-system-have-etc-sudoers-d-how-should-i-edit-it) that errors will not lock one out of their system. It has other advantages, but I don't know how useful they are for macOS users.

  Always use `sudo visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file - regardless of where it's been located on your system. This will avoid the need for an excursion into *Single User Mode* - especially important if the `su` command won't get you to the `root` prompt on your system (e.g. Catalina).

---

##### The "Addendum/FYI/Not part of the answer section":

###### Note 1:

I still find it odd that this works even before (and after) the `root` user was enabled... which beggars the question, *"What were they thinking?"*

###### Note 2:

As an aside, for those who are curious about `sh`:

```
% sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

:)  lol