# How to run non-Recovery Mode commands in macOS Recovery Mode terminal

Tags: terminal, recovery

So I want to escape all possible malware possible by using Recovery Mode. I am on a journey to try to make Recovery Mode like a usable account, and step one is running commands that are not built into the Recovery Mode terminal. Could anyone help me with running these commands or advising me on this project as a whole?

Comment: Is your question similar to the following question? [How to access commands included with macOS from macOS Recovery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437343/how-to-access-commands-included-with-macos-from-macos-recovery)

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. Recovery mode is in many ways *less* secure than normal mode. Many of the normal security layers in macOS aren't running (e.g. System Integrity Protection and the privacy controls built on it, all the built-in anti-malware stuff, etc), others are bypassed or bypassable, pretty much everything runs as root, etc. The only real sense in which Recovery mode is more secure is that you normally only run a small set of highly-trusted programs in it. As soon as you start running untrusted software, that security is *gone*.

Comment: A similar question has come up before, it is linked now on top of yours.

Comment: But to add to what Gordon already said: The assumption that Recovery Mode will *not* get infected with malware if you use it for day-to-day work is most likely wrong.